# ssh option via environment

Tags: ssh

I have a laptop, which I use both at work and at home.

When I am at work, I can ssh directly to any server I like.

When I'm at home, I have to go through a jumphost, to get on to the network.

I have a few entries like:

```
Host jump-server
  hostname server1
  proxyjump workproxy
```

but I have a LOT of servers, and a few scripts that I use which ssh to specific hosts also (which means they all need command-line options to specify use of jumphost or not).

Is there a way of automating this? For example, can I set an environment option so all hosts (except workproxy) should proxyjump?

Comment: You can always create a TAP tunnel via ssh and do routing via the jump server. Bit more complicated to setup, but so much easier to use. OR get in via a real VPN instead of an SSH server.

Comment: @meuh could you put that as an answer please, so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a specific answer, but you might get some ideas from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts) "Cookbook on Proxies and Jump Hosts".

If you use `Host *` and `ProxyCommand` with `%h` as the host you might be able to write a generic rule. And `Match` can work like `Host` but allows you to `exec` a command that can help reduce the `*` to match only those names you want to.

Comment: Thanks @meuh this led me to the right path. I have never come across "Match" before, this is the answer I was looking for. "Match" is hard to search for, the wikibooks link is very handy!

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with a `ProxyCommand` instead of `ProxyJump`. `ProxyCommand` here could be a shell script that checks for some variable and runs different commands.  For example, you could have a script `/some/proxy` like:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

if [ -n "$WORK" ] && [ "$1" != workproxy ]
then
    echo Work >&2
    ssh -qW "$1:$2" workproxy
else
    nc "$1" "$2"
fi
```

And SSH config:

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand /some/proxy %h %p
```

This checks if the `WORK` environment variable is not empty, and the host isn't `workproxy` and connects to workproxy. Otherwise it uses netcat to connect to the given host and port (effectively, a direct connection).

Comment: The other answer is simpler, unfortunately I can't mark both as accepted answers. I have +1'd it.